# How to change list sequence field register in prestashop 1.6?

Tags: sequence, prestashop

i want to change list sequence of field register in prestashop 1.6 like country - state - city, i have tried edit in *themes - default-bootsrap - address* but cannot work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change in to backoffice:

```
Localization -> Countries -> Edit the active country that you want to change the list
```

Then in Address format you can choose the order, change, and remove.

Comment: @Bekti perhaps you want to upvote this answer buddy, I did :D